# Syntax highlighting R script

Tags: r

As my R scripts get long and messy, I would like to create headers that are easily identifiable: for instance, change the color of certain comments in script.  I am not looking for something crazy like underlining or changing the fonts for chunks of comments, just changing color, i.e. highlighting comments.

From all my search, the only option is to change the Editor appearance from setting, but I would like to distinguish certain chunks of comments from other comments.

Comment: An alternative is try to avoid things getting messy. Group sections of code into functions wherever possible (you can do this even if the code is called only once - it may still help readability of the overall script).  Then group functions into separate files. Then you can use tabbed editing, with different related functions in different files. Finally load your functions up using `source` and make your main program an easy to read script made up of a sequence of function calls and possibly loops

Comment: Get a better editor.

Comment: @42-I have thought about it, yet as I am early in my R endeavor, was gonna wait till I get more use to R.  Still any suggestions, for instance I have read about ++Notepad or some others.  I would like something that I can easily setup to leverage with R.  Thanks.

Comment: The concept is not completely unprecedented: [`roxygen2`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/roxygen2/index.html) uses `#'` for its man-page-generating comments; [`plumber`](https://plumber.trestletech.com/) uses `#*` for its web-api defining comments. However, this is all *functional* differentiation; what you are asking for is *advice on editors* that somehow recognize these formats and do something different. I don't think RStudio allows this level of customization; Notepad++ and Sublime *might*, but I don't know them as well. Emacs/ESS has a steep curve if not already an emacs user.

Comment: Bottom line (for me): this sounds like you want to adapt the editor to better align with your programming organization (however "mature"/experienced it may be). This is much harder to do generically (for those who write the editors), so I believe the easier thing to do is define the simple concepts of programming (comments, data types, basic keywords, code blocks) and adjust "faces" (color, font, size, etc) from there. To do what you want, you may need to go elbow-deep into some (editor-specific) code or config and just figure it out.

Comment: Its now clear what I thought was the case.  i.e. if I want to do such an action within Rstudio its gonna require some pretty advanced settings manipulation, else try out another editor.  Thanks

Comment: You can do this in vscode with the Better Comments extension.

Answer (score 0):

I am not aware of changing colour of a specific comment, but you can **decorate** them like this:

```s
library(ARTofR)
xxx_title2("Example Title")

##~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
##                                Example Title                             ----
##~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

More functions at R pakcge `bannercommenter` and `ARTofR`